# SQL to group by and select a column when not null

Tags: sql

So I have a table like this:

```
ID  DESCRIPTION  AGROUP
-----------------------
1   AN  
2   FI  
3   DOC 1        DOC
4   DOC 2        DOC
5   CO  
6   RI           RI
```

If the AGROUP column is not null, I want to select and group by that value, otherwise select the DESCRIPTION; in any case order by ID. The result I want is:

```
ID  RESULT
-----------------------
1   AN  
2   FI  
3   DOC
5   CO  
6   RI
```

I've tried creating a subquery first, with

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT (NVL(AGROUP, DESCRIPTION)) AS DES 
FROM 
  temp
GROUP BY NVL(AGROUP, DESCRIPTION)
```

And then adding the outer query:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    DES 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT (NVL(AGROUP, DESCRIPTION)) AS DES 
        FROM 
    temp
        GROUP BY NVL(AGROUP, DESCRIPTION) 
) T1
JOIN TEMP T2 ON (T1.DES = T2.AGROUP OR T1.DES = T2.DESCRIPTION)
ORDER BY ID
;
```

But then I receive DOC twice:

```
1   AN
2   FI
3   DOC
4   DOC
5   CO
6   RI
```

SQL makes my head explode!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
select coalesce(AGROUP, DESCRIPTION) AS DES, min(id) as id
from  temp
group by coalesce(AGROUP, DESCRIPTION);
```

Comment: Oh my! COALESCE!!

Comment: @vulkanino . . . I have a strong preference for ANSI-standard functionality, unless there is a good reason to deviate.

Comment: And you are right @Gordon, I was just noting how simple it was the solution and I couldn't find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT (DESCRIPTION)) AS DES 
FROM 
temp
where AGROUP IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY (AGROUP, DESCRIPTION)
```

Comment: No this doens't do what requested, you select only the rows where group is not null.